# What bug is this

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image]

Found in Mojave county Az. It was in my home. I have a cat.  Real small about 1/8 inch

Comment: Three questions: 1) Did/does it have relatively long antennae not visible in picture? 2) Did you only find one? 3) Can you provide a top-down photo?

Comment: I can't tell if it has an antenna. I have found in past. Sorry this is the only pic

Comment: If viewed from above, does this insect appear to be very narrow (somewhat flat) from side to side, or does it look about as thick as a "normal" bug?